# Reading OpenXml documents in Streaming with SharePoint 2013 (By SahrePoint Office Web Apps Server or Office 360 )

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, openxml

I heard say that sharepoint 2013 can read documents OpenXml in streaming (loading page by page ). but I don't find information. Is it possible? else, have you a web site with information or key word to find it on google.

Answer (score 1):

This post should answer your question.
[Modifying Open XML Documents using the SharePoint Object Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/12/modifying-open-xml-documents-using-the-sharepoint-object-model.aspx)

It specifically addresses the issue of loading an OpenXml document from a SharePoint list into a resizable Memory Stream, modifying it, and saving it back.